# Vitest can't read CommonJS deps

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

I'm trying to migrate to `vitest` and facing a problem. One of the tests failed because it is reading a CommonJS file from one of the dependencies. The run does not fail on other tests that not using imports from CommonJS files

This is what my `defineConfig` in `vitest.config.ts` looks like:

```
import graphql from '@rollup/plugin-graphql';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    graphql(),
    react()
  ],
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    deps: {
      registerNodeLoader: true,
      fallbackCJS: true,
    },
  },
});
```

This is the error I got:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' 
file extension and '/Users/nadavnassi/Desktop/dev/admin-client/node_modules/@rapidapi/ui-lib-icons/package.json' 
contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Comment: try changing extension to jsx